# TruPhone-like VOIP?

Tags: 8.0

On iOS, Android and BB10, an app called "TruPhone" allows VOIP calls initiated by a call to a local (to the current country) landline which are then routed via the Internet to the destination phone network.

Is anything like that available for Windows Phone 8?

Comment: That sounds like something that doesn't need a dedicated app to work? Or do you mean something like Skype, where you can call real phones, but only pay for the call as a VOIP one?

Comment: Skype uses Internet bandwidth, TruPhone does not. It needs a dedicated app because something has to inform the provider that the next incoming call from the phone is supposed to be routed to whichever number was dialled in the dedicated app. How else could it be done?

Comment: It could be done by having a secondary dialing after entering account/destination details - kinda like companies like ACC did 20 years ago... Not heard of Truphone as a service though.

Answer (score 2):

From the [information on their website](http://www.truphone.com/US/Personal/Truphone-App/Overview/); Truphone operates over WiFi (rather than using the cellular network) as such, it would be akin to other VOIP services such as Skype. What they do appear to add is roaming agreements on major WiFi networks,  such as BT's, which mitigates the bandwidth consumption issue.

Comment: I have used TruPhone for six years. It does operate over WiFi, but it also works as I described. Why was this answer upvoted?

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm Probably it was upvoted because it is well written and it quotes the app website to back his answer. It is a community choice. If you do not agree just don't mask as answer or downvote explaining why you think it's wrong. I visited the site and looks like the info is correct making it pretty like the way Skype works on iOS. You can find in the source that they are "world's first **internet** calling service for smartphones"

Comment: The answer is wrong. TruPhone can use both WiFi and the cellular network. That is TruPhone's killer feature over Skype. The answer doesn't answer my question but "corrects" (wrongly) the reason I have for why I asked the question. It is simply not helpful as it creates the impression that Truphone works like Skype when Truphone offers more which is why I asked for something like Truphone on WP8.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm I don't understand how they offer anything over any other VOIP service, such as Skype; Whilst they say they work when there is no phone coverage, there is nothing that says you still need WiFi coverage; nor is there anything to suggest they don't just use the phone's data connection when there is no WiFi coverage.

Comment: I said how they do it in my question which is why I said this answer is not helpful. TruPhone offers a local telephone number which it calls. Only thence is the call routed via IP. So it's simply not true that TruPhone uses WiFi rather than the cellular network. It can use both and that's the difference between it and Skype.

Comment: Can you provide the source? They don't say this on their website as far as I know.